# How to select all values in drop down list by clicking a button using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I use this

```
$("select option").attr("selected", "true");
```

**Or**

```
$(function(){
    $('select').children('option').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

the list of dropdown will be selected automatically.

But in my position I should not use Iterator. Here both function using iterator. Here each and every option we set true or selected through iterator.

I need like if I set true to object of list, all the value of list should be selected without using loop or iterator.

Comment: If i use iterator add 1000 values, for each and evey option it iterates and show the values in another box. so that box scroll down will be scrolling down automatically. I should be ban that scroll down

Comment: @Twity You need to ask questions more clearly, if not we are all wasting our time trying to guess what you are trying to say. If English is not your first language, you can always use an online translator, like http://translate.google.com/, or ask it here in your native language and have someone translate it for you.

Comment: @YiJiang: I don't agree with that last part - *"ask it here in your native language and have someone translate it for you"*.  Posting a question in a different language will almost certainly result in down votes (I saw it happen the other day).

Comment: @Yi Jiang: more like ask it elsewhere in native language?

Comment: @Andy I assume you mean this - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62933/the-patricia-translation-problem - Well, sometimes there really isn't no other choice. Let's just put that question under the "things that should've never happened" file

Comment: @YiJiang: heh, maybe Google should work on translating input as well as output :-)

Answer (score 0):

The difference between selected="true" and selected="selected" is that one is for HTML and the other is for XHTML.

In HTML you use selected="true" (You used to just use selected, with no value, but using selected="true" is more explicit).

```
$("select option").attr("selected", "true");
```

In XHTML you use selected="selected"

```
$("select option").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Comment: It's a boolean DOM property in either case, so any non-empty string is `true`.

Comment: @Nick Craver - the question was specifically asking about the difference between true and selected, so I have explained where the two possible values come from.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do anything with a list of things, you iterate or enumerate through them (whichever the situation calls for), **this is how programming works**.  Just use the selectors the way they were intended, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('select option').attr('selected', true);
});
```